# Recyclerview run OutOfMemoryError every time

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I can't figure it out how to solve my problem. I hope you can help me :)

Everytime i run my RecyclerView with 10 Items everything is ok.
I can see the 4 first items on my mobile device screen when i start the App.
But when i try to start scrolling down my RecylcerView the app crashed with the following error: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" I have to say every item has more than 5 png images.

```
          FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:131)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:60)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:98)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:926)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:980)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at net.premates.SearchListActivity_old$1.onCreateViewHolder(SearchListActivity_old.java:69)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5223)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4449)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4359)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1161)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1018)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1492)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2416)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7817)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2435)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2441)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2326)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1612)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2494)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2274)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8025)
11-13 15:03:52.570 12519-12519/net.myname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.proce
```

This is the important part of my main activity main Activity:

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final ImageView image1;
        public final ImageView image2;
        public final ImageView image3;
        public final ImageView image4;
        public final ImageView image5;
        public final TextView text1;
        public final TextView text2;
        public final TextView text3;

        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            image1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton9);
            image2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton10);
            image3 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton11);
            image4 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton12);
            image5 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton13);
            text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1_);
            text2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            text3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text3);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_list);

        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        rv.setAdapter(new RecyclerView.Adapter() {

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return Note.getNoten().size();
            }

            @Override
            public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.search_list_row, viewGroup, false);
                return new MyViewHolder(v);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
                Note note = Note.getNoten().get(i);

                MyViewHolder mvh = (MyViewHolder) viewHolder;

                mvh.image1.setImageResource(note.image1);
                mvh.image2.setImageResource(note.image2);
                mvh.image3.setImageResource(note.image3);
                mvh.image4.setImageResource(note.image4);
                mvh.image5.setImageResource(note.image5);
                mvh.text1.setText(note.text1);
                mvh.text2.setText(""+note.text2);
                mvh.text3.setText( ""+note.text3);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my class Note: //It fills my ArrayList with data from an mysql database

```
public class Note {
    public final String text1;
    public final int int1;
    public final int image1;
    public final int image2;
    public final int image3;
    public final int image4;
    public final int image5;
    public final int int2;
    static InputStream is;
    static ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    static JSONObject json_data;
    static Boolean dataComplete = false;

    public Note(String text1, int int1, int int2, int image1, int image2, int image3, int image4, int image5) {
        this.text1 = text1;
        this.int1 = int1;
        this.int2 = int2;
        this.image1 = image1;
        this.image2 = image2;
        this.image3 = image3;
        this.image4 = image4;
        this.image5 = image5;
    }


    private static List<Note> noten;

    public synchronized static List<Note> getNoten() {
        if (noten == null) {
            noten = new ArrayList<Note>();
            getData();

            while(!dataComplete) // es soll solange gewartet werden bis die ArrayList ganz gefüllt ist und die Abfrage beendet wurde
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return noten;
    }

    public static void getData() {

        Thread t = new Thread() {

            private String result = "";
            public void run()
            {
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                try{
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("**********");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Fehler bei der http Verbindung " + e.toString());
                }

                try{
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    result=sb.toString();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                }

                try{
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        //results.add((String) json_data.get("ID") + " "+ json_data.get("text1"));
                        Log.e("log_tag", (String) json_data.get("int2") + " " + json_data.get("int1"));
                        int image1_status = Integer.parseInt((String) json_data.get("image1"));
                        int image2_status = Integer.parseInt((String) json_data.get("image2"));
                        int image3_status = Integer.parseInt((String) json_data.get("image3"));
                        int image4_status = Integer.parseInt((String) json_data.get("image4"));
                        int image5_status = Integer.parseInt((String) json_data.get("image5"));
                        if( image1_status == 1)
                            image1_status = R.drawable.image1_selected;
                        else
                            image1_status = R.drawable.image1_unselected;
                        if( image2_status == 1)
                            image2_status = R.drawable.image2_selected;
                        else
                            image2_status = R.drawable.image2_unselected;
                        if( image3_status == 1)
                            image3_status = R.drawable.image3_selected;
                        else
                            image3_status = R.drawable.image3_unselected;
                        if( image4_status == 1)
                            image4_status = R.drawable.image4_selected;
                        else
                            image4_status = R.drawable.image4_unselected;
                        if( image5_status == 1)
                            image5_status = R.drawable.image5_selected;
                        else
                            image5_status = R.drawable.image5_unselected;
                        noten.add(new Note((String) json_data.get("text1"), Integer.parseInt((String) json_data.get("int2")), Integer.parseInt((String)json_data.get("int1")), image1_status,image2_status,image3_status,image4_status,image5_status));

                    }
                    dataComplete = true;
                }
                catch(JSONException e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }

}
```

here is my search_list-row: You can see i use many images but i need them :/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/player"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/text1_"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/player_name"
        android:id="@+id/text1_"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/text2"
        android:id="@+id/text2_"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/rank_"
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text2_"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text1_"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/text1_"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text3_"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
            android:src="@drawable/image1_unselected"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
            android:src="@drawable/image2_unselected"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
            android:src="@drawable/image3_unselected"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton12"
            android:src="@drawable/image4_unselected"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton13"
            android:src="@drawable/image5_unselected"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/text3_"
        android:id="@+id/text3_"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/text3"
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text3_"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/text2" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/text3"
        android:background="@color/colorDivider"></FrameLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:src="@drawable/message"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope someone can help me :) Tanks!

Edite: I use Android Studio if this information is important :)

Comment: how large are the images?

Comment: and by size(how large) @Aegis meant width and height ... not png/jpg file size (as it doesn't matter)

Comment: One image is maybe 64 x 64 dp and the rest 5 images are 32 * 32 dp

Comment: use Image Loader Library for loading images... it will resolve your problem